# Problems Loading jQuery from CDN

Tags: jquery

I have written an intranet site, and it relies heavily on jQuery. To load jQuery I have been loading it from the jquery.com CDN and it works well. However, it has been reported by some users (using Firefox) that they can't use my site.

Debugging, I found that they all get a 404 error when trying to load the jQuery from here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

However, I'm using Firefox and have no problems with it.

Any idea why some users are having trouble?

Comment: Why do yo use CDN for *intranet*? "why some of them dont get the files" --- do they have internet connected?

Comment: @Dragnovich, You likely have some network appliance blocking those requests.  In any case, this isn't a problem with the HTML you show.

Comment: They wouldn't get a `404` error if they were blocked from the Internet. They would get a `timeout` or `connection error`. If they were being blocked by an appliance firewall, then they would likely get shown a HTML page from the appliance saying that resource is not available. A `404` error message is a response from an active web service that the `URL` did not point to a known resource.

Answer (score 3):

If this is an *intranet* application as you state, it is best to load jQuery from the local web server.  It will be much faster than going to a CDN.

You might well get this error if outbound firewall rules prevent connecting to the URLs listed in the CDN.  Try entering the URL of one of the JS files in the browser bar and see if you get a message from the firewall.  Also try observing the connection in the developer tools window (e.g on Internet Explorer press F12, then select Network tab).

Comment: Yes the intranet is on a "private server" how ever it has internet, and there's none proxy or firewall blocking....

Any way I will add the jquery to the server and load it locally... 

but the odd thing is that it does not work in JUST SOME fire fox browsers, any other browser and many test I did with firefox just 1 fail and others went well...

Comment: It fails in Firefox but loads correctly in a different browser *on the same computer*?  If so open the Web Console in FireFox (Ctrl-Shift-K) and note what is logged when you try to load jQuery from the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric says it is better to load JQuery from a local web server. And always ensure that you first list the path to your JQuery library and then mention the path to the JQuery file. I have explained this here [JQuery CDN Issue](https://rajiv2309.wordpress.com/2016/03/28/jquery-cdn-issue/)